# Gunicorn not loading react frontend in django react nginx configuration digitalocean

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, digital-ocean

i am trying to deploy django react app on digitalocean with nginx gunicorn. i have created the virtualenv and when i trying to run:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi
```

its doesn't load the react front but django backend loading. i am aware of that gunicorn does not static but it loading white page with error:

```
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since react needs the js library file to server, and it not rendered due to that it might be giving the error. server all the static file through nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/sample;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/django/sample/sample.sock;
    }
}
```